# Trouble understanding simple example of generator

Tags: python, generator, yield-keyword

I found these simple examples in several places:

```
# a generator that yields items instead of returning a list
def firstn(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1

sum_of_first_n = sum(firstn(1000000))

def get_primes(number):
    while True:
        if is_prime(number):
            yield number
        number += 1

def solve_number_10():
    total = 2
    for next_prime in get_primes(3):
        if next_prime < 1000:
            total += next_prime
        else:
            print(total)
        return
```

In the first example the generator exhausts itself, in the second it doesn't but the for loop is in charge of stopping the infinite generation.
A typical explanation says that `yield` "returns" a value, freezes the function state, and the function will continue from that state when called `next()`.
Isn't this explanation a bit misleading? In either example I cannot "visualize" anything that calls the generator function more than once (`next()`). Isn't it better said that `yield` returns a generator, which is an iterable object that can be iterated over only once?

Edit: a generator is not an iterable object either: it generates iterable objects on the fly, and what it "yields" (not "returns") can be iterated only once. This is bit mind-bending until I can properly grasp it, like a lot of other concepts :) Thank you.

Comment: The function returns a generator that can be iterated once—that a good way to describe it. To say that yield _returns_ something is a bit misleading, because it suggests that `yield` behaves similarly to `return`.

Comment: "a generator is not an iterable object either: it generates iterable objects on the fly" => actually, yes a `generator` __is__ an iterable - `generator` is a builtin type, which instances of are returned when calling a "generator function" or creating a "generator expression". If you want an in-depth explanation of how this is actually implemented, you can read this http://aosabook.org/en/500L/a-web-crawler-with-asyncio-coroutines.html -, starting at the "How Python Generators Work" chapter